Newlines in desktop notification body text?
When I show desktop notifications, e.g. through notify-send (but it also happens with an app I've written that goes directly to DBus), newlines in the body text get collapsed to spaces. Is there a way to separate the notification text into multiple short paragraphs for readability?
E.g., I want a notification like:

An error occurred processing the path:
/path/to/file
This may result in consistency issues.

When I send this to the notification server, though, I get:

An error occurred processing the path: /path/to/file This may result in consistency issues.


Ah, so the actual characters \ and n, rather than a character 10? Will give it a go, thanks. :-)

Hmm, it did not work. The \n was not replaced by a newline and appears in the notification verbatim. If I use a character 10, it gets treated like a space and the notification appears as a single line.

Can you please show us how you are generating and passing the message text to notify-send? In particular, remember that in many shells, unquoted variable expansions are subject to word splitting - which may explain what you are observing.

Hmm, okay, I did some experimenting and found that it is in fact quite difficult to literally pass a character 10 on the command-line to notify-send from a shell. I did succeed, however, and it produces an error: "Invalid number of options"

In further testing, if I write the command: notify-send "Notification test" "A\nB", then the process is passed a string literally containing a backslash and an n, but dbus-monitor shows a message with a newline between A and B. However, the resulting notification displays as "A B", as though the newline were a space.

My assertion that "A\nB" is passed as four characters 'A', '\', '\n', 'B' comes from the fact that if I write echo "A\nB" > testfile, then testfile contains these four characters, followed by a single newline at the end of the file.

I can create a file containing a newline between A and B with echo -e "A\nB" > testfile, and I can try passing this string to notify-send with notify-send "Notification test" $(cat testfile) or, indeed, notify-send "Notification test" $(echo -e "A\nB").

I just double-checked and on line 340, notify-send.c passes the body argument through the function g_strcompress, which is what turns a literal backslash followed by n passed on the command-line into a character 10 in the underlying message posted to DBus. https://github.com/GNOME/libnotify/blob/master/tools/notify-send.c#L340

Based on this investigation, the collapsing of the newlines must be happening at pretty much the end of the chain -- I'm pretty new to it so I don't know exactly what it's called, but the default UI in Ubuntu 24.04 (Gnome?) is apparently not permitting notifications to be formatted into multiple lines. :-(

In a bash shell, either notify-send $'foo\nbar' or notify-send "$(printf 'foo\nbar')" should work. Note that the command substitution itself needs to be double quoted to prevent split+glob i.e. your attempt with echo -e should be notify-send "Notification test" "$(echo -e "A\nB")"

Ah, that makes sense. Without the quoting, the '\n' is whitespace which splits A and B into different elements of argv. I can confirm that when properly quoted, passing the actual newline into notify-send produces exactly the same output as passing "\n" characters into notify-send: the message sent over DBus has an actual newline in it, and the notification that appears treats that newline as a space character. :-(

This appears to be the source of my woes: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/messageList.js#L548

Why is this downvoted? What is the thinking?

Almost every question gets downvoted at the moment - this was discussed in a recent meta post Has policy on downvotes changed? and seems just to be a phase the site is going through

And the answer is, sadly, apparently it is impossible. I think this analysis is correct. As far as I can tell, notificationDaemon.js uses a messageTray.js which wraps a messageList.js to actually display the notifications, and messageList.js actually originally comes from the calendar code and inherits some domain-specific behaviour from there.
It seems that:

Some time ago, Florian Müllner wrote some code to display a list of notification-like messages as part of calendar.js in gnome-shell.
Back in 2015, a change was made to filter out newlines when unexpanded:

commit b18240370d3ed7159e217197f01b0e06b8030946
Author: Florian Müllner <fmuellner@gnome.org>
Date:   Tue Mar 10 23:36:09 2015 +0100

    calendar: Filter out newlines when unexpanded
    
    Enabling line-wrapping of the unexpanded body is not enough to enforce
    a single line when the text has embedded newlines, so replace these with
    spaces (this is similar to setting ClutterText:single-line-mode, however
    that would use a paragraph separator glyph instead).


In 2016, the message list control was split out of the calendar to separate files, making it reusable.
This control then got reused for displaying system notifications.
The code that collapses newlines for unexpanded calendar notifications is still there.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/messageList.js#L548
My mostly-uninformed guess is that the collapsing of newlines to spaces should apply to a notification that has not been expanded, but when it is clicked on to make it display fully, then it shouldn't be collapsed. But, in the calendar, this expansion is done by fully replacing the control, whereas in the notifications code it's just adjusting the display size of the control, so the collapsed text is still collapsed.
I could be completely off-base here but that's what it looks like to me.

I have been working on engaging the design process and development team to see if this can be changed. Responses have been varied, from "I doubt things are going to change" to "If newlines really are being removed, that's going to be very annoying!" The main place for discussing these things seems to be a space called "Whiteboard" in GNOME GitLab.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/Teams/Design/whiteboards/-/issues/251
